# Command line from NetBeans doesn't see mapped drives

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line

I am executing a batch file from the command line, from within java.

The batch file runs a ruby file on a PC on our network. Actual CL: "C:\CreateOrder.bat" Within the batch file, I change to a mapped drive, then execute a ruby script on that mapped drive (both the java and Ruby code are used in automated qa).

In Java, I run the batch file from the command line, accessed through the RunTime class. This was originally developed in Eclipse, and works fine there. I recently moved to NetBeans, and now the batch file will still run, but the command line has no knowledge of any mapped drives, and therefore cannot execute the Ruby script.

I did some tests where I have NetBeans open up a CL window, and found I can not change to, or list the contenets of any mapped network drive.

The most obvious difference between Eclipse and Netbeans is that the CL window in NetBeans opens with the NetBeans project folder as its target: C:\nbprojects\.

So far, I have tried: 
- running the commands within the batch file with UNC paths instead of mapped drives 
- making sure the project folder permissions for NetBeans are the same as Eclipse 
- running a CL that open a cmd window first, then execute the batch file: (cmd /c start C:\CreateOrder.bat).

I am at a loss here. I must be missing something simple. How can I run a CL from NetBeans, where the CL has access to my mapped drives?

Thanks.